# Add XDeclaration to XDocument after it's constructed

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xml-serialization, xmlserializer

I have an XmlSerializer which I use to Serialize an object to an XDocument.

```
var doc = new XDocument();
using (var writer = doc.CreateWriter())
{
   xmlSerializer.Serialize(writer, object);
}
```

After this is done, I want to add a XDeclaration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
```

I construct this XDeclaration as described below:

```
var decl = new XDeclaration("1.0", "UTF-8", "no");
```

However, when I try to add this XDeclartion to my XDocument, I get the following error:

```
System.ArgumentException : Non white space characters cannot be added to content.
```

I searched Google for some time but all I've found is adding the XDeclaration to the constructor of the XDocument which in my case (when filling it with a XmlWriter) is not acceptable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use property [XDocument.Declaration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.declaration.aspx)

---

**EDIT**:

Sample code:

```
var xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(int));

var doc = new XDocument();

var decl = new XDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", "no");
doc.Declaration = decl;

using (var writer = doc.CreateWriter())
{
    xmlSerializer.Serialize(writer, 1);
}
doc.Save(File.Create("x.xml"));
```

This code produced following output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?>
<int>1</int>
```

Comment: Then I'm missing something else.
I copied your code, but my output is:

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16" standalone="no"?>
<int>1</int>`

Comment: Allthough it did not work on my pc, I believe this answer is so basic and trivial, it must be something else which keeps me from getting the right XDeclaration above my xml

Comment: In a larger application it worked for me only when flushing and closing the writer before the save. As well as no File.Create in the Save function. `writer.Flush(); writer.Close(); doc.Save("Import.xml");`